# JScrollPane not working correctly

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a GUI where the left side holds an image and the right side is a panel which holds some label objects. I want it so that if there are more objects on the right panel than can fit, a scroll bar will appear.

The problem I have is that when a lot of objects are added to the right panel, the whole frame resizes.

Here are some screenshots. THe first one is the size I want the window to always be and the second image shows the resizing issue.

[image: Correct size]
Second image:
[image: Incorrect size]

Here is the code for the panel which holds the image panel and the side bar panel:

```
/**
 * image panel - displays image and editing area
 */
ImagePanel imagePanel = null;

// Holds the labels
private LabelHolder lHolder = new LabelHolder();

/**
 * handles New Object button action
 */
public void addNewPolygon() {
  imagePanel.addNewPolygon(null);
}

public ContainerPanel(String imageFilename, JFrame frame) {
  //setup main window panel 
  addComponents(imageFilename, frame);
}

public void addComponents(String imageFilename, JFrame frame) {
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  // Polygon Title
  JLabel labelPanelTitle = new JLabel("<html><b>Polygons</b></html>");
  labelPanelTitle.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 150));
  Font f = new Font("LabelPanel", Font.PLAIN, 24);     
  labelPanelTitle.setFont(f);
  labelPanelTitle.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

  // Create and set up the image panel.
  try {
    imagePanel = new ImagePanel(imageFilename, frame, this);
  } catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
  }
  imagePanel.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque

  JPanel objectsPanel = new JPanel();
  objectsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(objectsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

  JPanel labelHolderContainer = new JPanel();
  labelHolderContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labelHolderContainer, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

  labelHolderContainer.add(lHolder);        

  JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(labelHolderContainer); 

  // add the title
  objectsPanel.add(labelPanelTitle);
  // Add a spacer
  objectsPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,25)));
  // Add all the labels
  objectsPanel.add(scroller);

  addNewLabel("Some Object");
  addNewLabel("Some Object");
  addNewLabel("Some Object");
  addNewLabel("Some Object");
  addNewLabel("Some Object");
  addNewLabel("Some Object");
  addNewLabel("Some Object");
  addNewLabel("Some Object");
  addNewLabel("Some Object");
  addNewLabel("Some Object");
//      addNewLabel("Some Object");
//      addNewLabel("Some Object");
//      addNewLabel("Some Object");
//      addNewLabel("Some Object");

  add(imagePanel);
  add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));
  add(objectsPanel);

}   

public void addNewLabel(String labelName) {
  lHolder.add(new Label(labelName, imagePanel.getCurrentColour()));
  lHolder.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,10)));

  // set new colour 
  imagePanel.setCurrentColour(imagePanel.getRandomColour());
}
```

Comment: Change the layout from FlowLayout to a BorderLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- have to override max size for parent of `JScrollPane`, or override `JPanel` (inside `JScrollPane`) helt whatever demonstrated on pictures, no idea for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)
- in the case that you want to natural scrolling (no issue to put `Icons` with narrative) then to
- use [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
- use [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) with one Column

EDIT

remove `JFrame#pack()` from method(s) to `add` / `modify` / `remove` Items in `JScrollPane`, otherwise isn't possible change size of `Top-Level Containers` on the Screen

Answer (score 1):

You try taking advantage of the [`Scrollable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) interface.

[image: Test]

```
public class TestScroll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestScroll();
    }

    public TestScroll() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                ScrollablePane content = new ScrollablePane();
                content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
                try {
                    imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/swhitehead/Dropbox/issue169.jpg"))));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                content.add(imageLabel);

                ScrollablePane listPane = new ScrollablePane();
                listPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
                for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
                    listPane.add(new JLabel("This is a simple test - " + index));
                }

                content.add(new JScrollPane(listPane), BorderLayout.EAST);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(content);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ScrollablePane extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 100);
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 100;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 100;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```